# android studioで+指定で読み込んだライブラリのバージョンを確認するには

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

build.gradleファイルにて、
dependenciesの項目で、+指定で読み込んだライブラリのバージョンを確認するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gradle :app:dependencies`

のような感じで、対象プロジェクトの`dependencies`タスクを実行してあげると依存ライブラリのバージョンが表示されます。いろいろな種類の依存ツリーが表示されますが、`compile`や`testCompile`を見ればだいたい必要な情報はわかると思います。

例えば`testCompile`を見ると、以下のように `4.+`が`4.12`に展開されていることがわかると思います。

```
testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
\--- junit:junit:4.+ -> 4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

これをAndroid Studioから実行したい場合は、メニューの`View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`から`Gradle project`ビューを表示させ、そこに表示されているツリーから`:app`の`Tasks -> help -> dependencies`で実行できます。

Answer (score 3):

**`build.gradle`**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.+'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

task printActualVersion() << {
  // test依存関係にも含まれるので不要
  // configurations.compile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts().each {
  //   println it.getName() + ": " + it.getModuleVersion().getId().getVersion()
  // }
  configurations.testCompile.getResolvedConfiguration().getResolvedArtifacts().each {
    println it.getName() + ": " + it.getModuleVersion().getId().getVersion()
  }
}
```

上のような`printActualVersion`タスクを自身のビルドスクリプトに追記すれば、`gradle printActualVersion`(あるいは`gradlew printActualVersion`)コマンドの出力で確認できるかと思います。

出力例:

```
$ gradle printActualVersion
:printActualVersion
commons-collections: 3.2.2
junit: 4.12
hamcrest-core: 1.3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

参考: [java - In Gradle, how can I generate a POM file with dynamic dependencies resolved to the actual version used? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959558/)